# How do I use xte to bind next/previous to my mouse?

Tags: xte

I know how to use xbindkeys, but I don't know what is the xte command for previous/next, when I want to bind my extra mouse buttons to navigate nautilus/web browser to go 1 step back or 1 step forward.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons 6 and 7 are already bound to previous/back and next/forward in most important applications. Use `xmodmap` to remap them to the desired buttons on the mouse.